# Opening and listening to multiple eventsources

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, server-sent-events

I have an api that sends messages like 'data', 'patch', and 'error' that I can listen to and respond to. I am trying to listen to several(about 30) of these with only a different query (i.e listen to "Atlanta Hawks" vs "New York Knicks").
I'm not completely sure how to do this.

I have tried to open a connection by looping through an array. then, listen to events on all these sources. However, the for loop just loops forever (I hit the request limit in a 2 min :( )

```
for(var i=0; i<teamList.length; i++){
      //open a new event source with the teamname
      var eventsource = new EventSource(streamdata + teamList[i] + streamtoken);
      //this was logged a million times :(
      eventsource.onopen = function(){
        console.log(teamList[i] + " connected!");
      };
eventsource.addEventListener('data', function(item) {
      //mess with 'item'
});
```

Edit

---

This is what I tried. I was able to get the data and mess with it but it seems to loop forever.

```
for(var i=0; i<teamList.length; i++){
      var teamStream = global[eventsource[i]];
      var teamStream = new EventSource(streamdata + teamList[i] + streamtoken);

      teamStream.onopen = function(){
        console.log(teamStream + " connected!");
      };

      teamStream.addEventListener('data', function(item) {
      //set teamName as the query sent to api
      var data = JSON.parse(item.data);
      teamName = data.query;
      console.log('got data from ' + teamName);
      //set firebase node as the query sent to api
      var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase('https://shining-inferno-1085.firebaseio.com/' + teamName);
      //set initial data with returned api data
      myFirebaseRef.set(data);
    });

      teamStream.addEventListener('patch', function(patch) {
      var item = JSON.parse(patch.data);
      console.log("patch is " + item);
      if(patch.data[0].path !== "/time") {
          myFirebaseRef.push(patch.data);
       }
    });

    teamStream.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
      console.log('ERROR!');
      console.log(e.data);
      teamStream.close();
    });
  }
```

Let me know if you can see the problem or if I'm on the right track

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use one `EventSource` with named events?

```
event: userlogon\n
data: {"username": "John123"}\n\n
```

Then a different event handler for each.

```
source.addEventListener('userlogon', function(e) { var data = JSON.parse(e.data); console.log('User login:' + data.username); }, false);
```

Comment: Do you have a link or could you clarify a bit. I'm not sure I understand, if I have multiple urls to listen to like (url1, url2, url3) how would I connect to them in your example?

Comment: Look at the Specifying Event Name section of this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/. I'm essentially saying that you should combine all your EventSources into one. I don't know the architecture of your application, but that should really help with your stated issue.

Comment: @baynezy , could you add an example of a single `EventSource` listening to multiple URLs? I understand that's valuable, but I don't understand how to do that

Comment: Ah, are you advocating combining all the client/server communication into a single URL? If so, how does that work if I'm passing parameters in the `EventSource` URL e.g. `EventSource("https://example.com/?name=me&age=209")` ?

Answer (score 1):

May be you could rewrite your query so that instead of 30 queries, you have only one and then process the response to dispatch the results to 30 « responses processors »?
In the spirit, something like that:

```
var myComplexQuery = ...
var teamStream = new EventSource(myComplexQuery);

teamStream.addEventListener('data', function(item) {
  var data = JSON.parse(item.data);
  var extractedData = {};
  extractedData = splitDataInto30Responses(data);
  for(var i=0; i<teamList.length; i++) { 
     // do whatever with your data
     var teamName = teamList[i];
     process(extractedData[teamName]);
  }

});
```